# Mousemove events not registering after window.resize event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events

For whatever reason, natively in Chrome, `mousemove` events that immediately follow a `mousedown` event are not firing or are simply ignored altogether for a small period of time (500-1000ms?) following the `mousedown` event.

Strange thing is that this issue is nonexistent on codepen (on Chrome too) and **the code is the exact same...** There's also no issues with Firefox, Edge, etc, only natively on Chrome.

**[Here is a codepen nonetheless.](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/LebdMG) Test it for yourself.**

Copy and paste this code into actual .html, .css, and .js files, and then run it in the browser directly, you'll notice that `paper.onmousemove` does not fire or register immediately after a `window.resize` event for a very small period of time.

None of this makes any sense!

Anybody have any idea what's going on? **Why would it work fine in codepen (and every other browser), yet not directly in the browser?!**

I have found one issue with the codepen version, which produces a very similar bug (but involves a couple extra steps in the beginning).

1. Create an element by dragging your mouse on the white area
2. Select that element by clicking it
3. Drag that element anywhere on the page
4. Resize the browser and immediately try to create another element by dragging

However, on codepen `mousedown` isn't firing in this case, whereas `mousemove` is not firing if viewed directly in the browser. Again, there is a discrepancy, which incredibly bizarre.

## Update

It turns out it only happens when the developer console is open, which is why it was not happening in codepen.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: As far as I'm aware, a codepen running on Chrome and "native" JS are the exact same thing.

Comment: @charlietfl can't provide an MCV because the issue is something with my code.  i would post a codepen, but the issue doesn't happen in codepen, only when the page is viewed directly in the browser

Comment: Well clearly there is something different between the version that has the issue and the other version. We can't guess what that might be

Comment: @charlietfl they are identical... that's why it's so goddamn frustrating. hence i'm assuming it has something to do with the way codepen processes the code which corrects the issue

Comment: @charlietfl there is a codepen for u

Comment: @ChrisG you know what i mean...

Comment: something has to be different to get different behaviors in same browser

Comment: @charlietfl i've edited my question and provided a lot more info. there is a way to reproduce a very similar bug in codepen (which is also a bug when viewed outside of codepen).

Comment: @charlietfl absolutely nothing is different. test it for yourself...

Comment: If you resize the frame on codepen, the bug doesn't occur. Resize the chrome window while looking at the codepen however, and it does indeed occur. So I guess one mystery solved.

Comment: @ChrisG not for me. even if i resize the actual browser, the bug still does ***not*** happen...

Comment: @Anthony I opened the console and dragged its upper edge to cause a window.resize event. Bug occurs.

Comment: @ChrisG the ***other*** bug occurs (the one i showed u how to reproduce with steps above) but the original bug does ***not*** occur whether you resize the codepen console or even the browser itself.

Comment: FWIW, I can only replicate this bug when Chrome Dev Tools is open. It immediately goes away when I close Dev Tools. With Dev Tools open, it starts logging mouse movies immediately when the resolution label in the top right disappears.

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager omg wtf. youre right. and that's precisely why it isn't happening in codepen despite being the exact same code.

Comment: @charlietfl the reason it wasn't happening in codepen, but was happening independently is because it only seems to happen when the developer console is open...

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager draft up an answer and ill select it <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be some weirdness with Chrome DevTools. The bug you describe seems to only occur when DevTools is open. It goes away when you close DevTools. It may just be a weird coincidence, but it starts logging out `mousemove` events immediately when the resolution label in the top right goes away.

That being said, you have a combination of `onmousemove` and `addEventListener` going on. For instance you have both

`paper.addEventListener('mouseup', checkMouseUp)`

and

`paper.onmouseup = function(event) {}`

I'm not sure if it's the cause of the DevTools issue, but this can lead to unintended consequences since `paper` now has two separately assigned `mouseup` functions. In your case, I'd just stick with `addEventListener`.

Comment: yeah, i know i have multiple listeners for the same event. i do this to segregate code with different purposes. i plan to clean it up and lkikely segregate it even further. strange thing is this doesn't happen in any other browser either :/

Comment: I've just encountered this too with similar symptoms to OP and I only have event listeners (i.e. nothing like `onmouseup`). So definitely a bug in devtools.